# How to restrict ol, ul css to a div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to restrict ol, ul css to a particular section (div). Below is the code. I'm trying to apply css for ul present only in the first div. But it applies the css for ul present in both div. How to restrict it only to the first div section ? I do not want to use a css class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
       #menu ol, ul {
        list-style: none;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>My First CSS Example</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
       </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
      <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
       </ul>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that comma-separated selectors are treated "as new" and do not depend on previous selectors. You should use: `#menu ol, #menu ul`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

When you use comma seperated selectors to the css rule it applies to both of them. So the second selector `ul` applies for both divs